# execute custom sql with entity framework4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have to receive workorders from the database, specific for the user.

The filter for all users is different, so one must do all order shipped to UK, ont all to 5 other countries, one does all the high value things, one does al the order which containt > 10 items etc.

So, what i came up with this idea (shoot at it if you have a better one!)

i create a view for each user, and all the views return the same data, but the filter is different.

In ado.net i would do something like this:

```
string sql = "select * from vwWorkOrders" + userName;
[rest of the ado.net here]
```

but now i'm using ef4, and i was wondering what is the equivalent of this kind of code.

Comment: that is the name of the user, so if i am logged on, i would like to select all data from vwWorkOrdersMichel and if you're logged on, i would like to select al; data from vwWorkOrdersSaeed

Comment: please do not create a view for each user or my eyes will bleed

Comment: @Richard, as i said: shoot at it if you have a better idea. Reading your sarcastic remark gives me the idea you have a way better idea, so if you would like to share it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [ExecuteStoreQuery method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) like in the following example:

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<vwWorkOrder>(sql);
```

This method allows you to execute storage SQL and obtain strongly-typed results.
In case you need to pass some parameters, just pass necessary ObjectParameter instances in the call of ExecuteStoreQuery.

Comment: i think this is excactly what i want, i'll try it right away!

Answer (score 3):

You can use eSQL, which allows for a little more flexibility in your queries. You might download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to play around with it beforehand.

```
// whereClause is a string
string query = string.Format("select * from ObjectContext.vwWorkOrders where {0}", whereClause);
```

Then just use the `EntityConnection` and `EntityCommand` classes to execute your command and loop over the results in a manner not altogether different from ADO.NET.

EDIT: I just saw your comment; I thought that you had a typo in your example. A more suitable code snippet for what you are trying to achieve:

```
// userName is a string, ie "Michel"
string query = string.Format("select * from ObjectContext.vwWorkOrders{0}", userName);
```