# Specifying where clause format in Entity Framework with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, system.data.sqlite

I have an Entity Framwework 4.0 Model running against an SQLite database to which I connect via System.Data.SQLite. I have one field in the database which is typed "Date", and formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`. (As we know, SQLite has no internal Date or DateTime type).

The Entity Framework wizard happily translated that Date type to DateTime. When running queries against this date field, I was surprised to find out no results came.

Suppose a table "MyTable":

```
Create Table MyTable
(
    Id Integer Not Null Primary Key,
    ADate Date Not Null
);
```

With System.Data.SQLite and LINQ:

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
context.MyTables.AddObject(new MyTable { Id = 0, ADate = date });
context.SaveChanges();
context.MyTables.Where(r => r.ADate == date).Count; // -> returns 0
```

Looking further with `ToTraceQuery`, I found out that the query became:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[ADate] AS [ADate]
FROM [TestDate] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ADate] = @p__linq__0
```

With testing, I discovered that the mapped variable `p__linq__0` was transformed to a fixed format of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, so that asking for `DateTime(2013,1,1)` meant the query was looking for `'2013-01-01 00:00:00'` when all that was to be found was `'2013-01-01'`.

If the folks who make 'System.Data.SQLite' had been nice about this, they'd have used the built in SQLite functions and done the comparison like:

```
WHERE datetime([Extent1].[ADate]) = datetime(@p__linq__0)
```

or even

```
WHERE date([Extent1].[ADate]) = date(@p__linq__0)
```

for just the date type. And indeed in System.Data.SQLite's [SqlGenerator.cs](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/871b9632d428a2d5d17c6c751463d97c1320cc8d), we find this formatting for all DateTime types:

```
((System.DateTime)e.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), false /* IsUnicode */)
```

All this to say, **is there a way to specify the format for this where clause in this context?**

Notes: SQLite is what I'm stuck with, and the recorded format of 'yyyy-MM-dd' cannot be changed as other software relies on it.

Comment: Going through `DateTime.Compare` does not change the format used...

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute custom sql with entity framework4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185248/execute-custom-sql-with-entity-framework4)

Comment: `context.MyTables.Count(r => r.ADate == date)` should work better

Comment: and `AData` is a bad name for the column, it breaks all the guidelines and conventions.

Comment: @abatishchev I tried `.Equals` and `==` and they both do the same. Both convert to the exact same SQL. `ADate` is just a mockup name for the purposes of the question, my table isn't really named "MyTable" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative to `ExecuteStoreQuery` is to pass other where clauses first (if any) then force the query to run (for example with `ToList()`), and finally to apply standard LINQ filters on the special format Date field afterwards.